# JavaScript - input array changed without push statement

Tags: javascript, arrays

I was on leet code #283

> Given an array nums, write a function to move all 0's to the end of it
>   while maintaining the relative order of the non-zero elements.
>
> Input: [0,1,0,3,12]
>    Output: [1,3,12,0,0]

Can somebody please explain the following code.

```
var moveZeroes = function(nums) {     // nums is [0,1,0,3,12]
  var len = nums.length;
  for (let lastNonZero = 0, cur = 0; cur < len; cur++) {
    if (nums[cur] !== 0) {
      [nums[lastNonZero], nums[cur]] = [nums[cur], nums[lastNonZero]];    // what exactly happened here
      lastNonZero++;
    }
  }
  return nums;
};
```

How did the `for loop` work and how is the `nums array` rearranged?

Comment: you may take a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[nums[lastNonZero], nums[cur]] = [nums[cur], nums[lastNonZero]];`

This is a es6 syntax called de de-structuring, whats happening there is a just a swap.

example of object destructuring

```
obj = { 'a': 1, 'b': 2}
const { a, b } = obj;
```

instead of accessing obj.a everywhere you can now just use a, which is destructed as local variable.

similarly lets consider an array

```
arr = [1,2,3];
const [a,b,c] = arr;

console.log(a) will result in 1;
```

Essentially, the first element in the array is assigned to the first variable int the array.
Hope it clarifies.

Comment: destructuring keyword

Answer (score 3):

I believe The following

```
[nums[lastNonZero], nums[cur]] = [nums[cur], nums[lastNonZero]];
```

is short for

```
nums[lastNonZero] = nums[cur];
// and
nums[cur] = nums[lastNonZero];
```

but simultaneously with out doing

```
const tempCurrent = nums[cur];
const tempLastNonZero = nums[lastNonZero];
nums[lastNonZero] = tempCurrent;
nums[cur] = tempLastNonZero;
```

Edit:

destructuring is the name of this syntax thanks to [@SanthoshN](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54833894/6656422)

[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) from [@gaetanoM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833699/javascript-input-array-changed-without-push-statement#comment96442615_54833699) and [@Jacque Goupil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833699/javascript-input-array-changed-without-push-statement#comment96442722_54833856) is what that is

Comment: This syntax is known as a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). I wouldn't have thought of using it for a swap, it's a clever trick.

Answer (score 3):

The line: `[nums[lastNonZero], nums[cur]] = [nums[cur], nums[lastNonZero]]` is just replacement. If you have `[1, 2]` and use this code, you'll end up with `[2, 1]`. The function you provided will run through the loop and move 0 to the right and the next number to the left, until it gets to [0, 0].

Answer (score -1):

`[nums[lastNonZero], nums[cur]] = [nums[cur], nums[lastNonZero]]` just do swapping.

```js
let [a,b] = ['b','a']

console.log(a,b)
```

Alternate method is to use [**filter**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [**concat.**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Here idea is

- By filter we take all non zero element in a variable.
- Add number of zero equal to length of `original arr - filtered arr`

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,0,15,10,82,19,0,5,8,7]

let op = arr.filter(e=>e)

let final = op.concat(new Array(arr.length - op.length).fill(0))

console.log(final)
```

Comment: The OP asked for an explanation of the given code, not an alternative solution. (Even if I do like this solution more than the given one.)